# Music File Manager Urgent Question

Tags: applications, jailbreak, data-transfer, file, id3-tag

Does anyone know of an iPhone/iPod app, or jailbreak, that is a music downloader manager AND a tag editor that lets you add album art? I've been searching everywhere for an app that downloads music and lets me change/add album artwork (within the download manager app), but I've had absolutely no luck.

It would just make it 100000 times easier for me to import the music files to my computer, without having to edit each file's tags and artwork from my PC. It's time consuming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to edit album art directly on your iPhone, there are no iPhone apps to do that, but there are Windows apps which could help. I've used [Tune Sweeper](http://wideanglesoftware.com/) in the past to download album art and correct incorrect track info on my iTunes library. You can then re-sync your iPhone to iTunes which will update the music files on the phone too. 
[image: download iTunes album art]